# How do I fix my partitions?

Tags: partitioning, raspberrypi, fdisk

I installed Ubuntu for an rPi 2 on an 8GiB micro SD card. However, when I subsequently set about installing software I ran out of space. That's because I forgot to repartition immediately after installation. However, I think I screwed up my repartitioning attempt and am wondering whether I can undo things to get back on track.

Here's what I did:

First, I checked `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                           1.7G  1.6G     0 100% /
devtmpfs                            458M  4.0K  458M   1% /dev
none                                4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                 93M  380K   93M   1% /run
none                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                462M     0  462M   0% /run/shm
none                                100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p1                       64M   20M   45M  31% /boot/firmware
```

I then ran `sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0`, and viewed the partition list:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7948 MB, 7948206080 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 242560 cylinders, total 15523840 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *        2048      133119       65536    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          133120     3670015     1768448   83  Linux
```

Next, I deleted the second partition, and recreated it as a primary, this time allocating all available space. I typed `w` to write it, then exited and rebooted my pi.

However, after a reboot the output of `df -h` looks the same. So I'm confused about where all the extra allocated space went, and how I can allocated it to my root file system.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I forgot a step:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Now a `df -h` looks like:

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                           7.2G  1.6G  5.3G  23% /
devtmpfs                            458M  4.0K  458M   1% /dev
none                                4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                 93M  372K   93M   1% /run
none                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                462M     0  462M   0% /run/shm
none                                100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow                            1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1                       64M   20M   45M  31% /boot/firmware
```